# Finding a transition matrix $P_{B'\leftarrow B}$ and using it to find $B'$ coordinate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here are my full instructions:

> Find the transition matrix $P_{B'\leftarrow B}$ from $B=\left\{\left(1,1,\right),\left(2,3\right)\right\}$ to $B'=\left\{\left(1,2\right),\left(0,1\right)\right\}$, and use it to find the $B'$ coordinate matrix for the vector with $B$ coordinate matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ -4 \\  \end{bmatrix}_B$.

So I did the following:

$\begin{bmatrix} B' & B  \\ \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, $rref = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

So I said $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ -1 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}^T$ and then $\begin{bmatrix} X  \end{bmatrix}_{B'} = P\begin{bmatrix} X  \end{bmatrix}_{B} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ -1 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ -4 \\  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -3 \\  \end{bmatrix}$

Am I correct up to this point and do I then take my coordinates and apply them to $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, letting $P_{\mathscr{B}' \leftarrow \mathscr{B}}$ denote the transition matrix from the basis $\mathscr{B}$ to the basis $\mathscr{B}'$, 
$$P_{\mathscr{B}' \leftarrow \mathscr{B}} = P_{\mathscr{B}' \leftarrow \mathscr{E}}P_{\mathscr{E} \leftarrow \mathscr{B}}\\=P_{\mathscr{E} \leftarrow \mathscr{B}'}^{-1}P_{\mathscr{E} \leftarrow \mathscr{B}}\,\,,$$
where $\mathscr{E}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  You know each of these matrices in the final equality I have given: you need only take the inverse of the matrix with columns the basis vectors of $\mathscr{B}'$.  The other matrix is just that formed by the basis vectors of $\mathscr{B}$ as columns. After you compute the desired transition matrix by taking the product of these two known matrices, you need to multiply it by the $\mathscr{B}$-coordinate vector on the right to obtain the $\mathscr{B}'$-coordinate vector.  In other words, $$P_{\mathscr{B}' \leftarrow \mathscr{B}} \cdot \left[\vec{x}\right]_{\mathscr{B}} = \left[\vec{x}\right]_{\mathscr{B}'}\,\,.$$